# Помогите зациклить код Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, распознавание-речи, pyttsx3

Никак не получается зацклить данного "недоассистента", чтобы он выполнял комманды, пока я не скажу стоп. Пытался выставлять переменные с True и False в функции, но ничего нормального из этого не вышло.
В конце я поставил в цикл '''time.sleep(0.1)''' для того, чтобы ассистент успел полностью произнести ответ, иначе же код сразу перестанет работать
Скинул вам изначальный код, ещё до экспериментов над циклом.

```
# ПЕРЕД ЗАПУСКОМ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО УСТАНОВИТЬ МОДУЛИ (В том порядке, в котором они даны(ВАЖНО!)):
# если вы используете PyCharm, то py -m писать не обязательно
# py -m pip install pywin32
# py -m pip install pypiwin32
# py -m pip install pyttsx3
# py -m pip install SpeechRecognition
# py -m pip install wikipedia
# https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio (Модуль PyAudio скачивать по этой ссылке в соответсвии
# с вашей версией Python) зайдите в cmd и укажите папку в которой находится модуль PyAudio.whl, после чего
# вводите комманду py -m pip install (полное название файла.whl)
# py -m pip install fuzzywuzzy


import os
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import requests
import sys
import math
import wikipedia
import re

appid = "сюда свой айди на weathermap"
voice = ''

# настройки
opts = {
    "alias": ('саня', 'саша', 'александр', 'сашок', 'сашка', 'сашик',
              'санёк', 'санек', 'санчо', 'сань', 'саш'),
    "tbr": ('скажи', 'расскажи', 'покажи', 'сколько', 'произнеси'),
    "cmds": {
        "ctime": ('текущее время', 'сейчас времени', 'который час'),
        "radio": ('включи музыку', 'воспроизведи радио', 'включи радио'),
        "stupid1": ('расскажи анекдот', 'рассмеши меня', 'ты знаешь анекдоты'),
        "weather": ('погода в городе', 'погоду в городе'),
        "wikipedia": ('что такое', 'кто такой', 'кто такая', 'определение слова', 'определение слову', 
        'что значит')
    }
}


# функции
def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()


def callback(recognizer, audio):
    global voice
    try:
        voice = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU").lower()
        print("[log] Распознано: " + voice)

        if voice.startswith(opts["alias"]):
            # обращаются к Сане
            cmd = voice

            for x in opts['alias']:
                cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

            # распознаем и выполняем команду
            cmd = recognize_cmd(cmd)
            execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])

            return voice

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("[log] Голос не распознан!")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("[log] Неизвестная ошибка, проверьте интернет!")
    return voice
    

def recognize_cmd(cmd):
    RC = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
    for c, v in opts['cmds'].items():
    
        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > RC['percent']:
                RC['cmd'] = c
                RC['percent'] = vrt

    return RC


def execute_cmd(cmd):
    if cmd == 'ctime':
        # сказать текущее время
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        speak("Сейчас " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute))

    elif cmd == 'radio':
        # воспроизвести радио
        os.system("Тут ссылка на программу радио в проводнике")

    elif cmd == 'stupid1':
        # рассказать анекдот
        speak("Мой разработчик не научил меня анекдотам ...")

    elif cmd == 'weather':
            
            weathervoice = voice
            a = weathervoice.split('\n')
            for x in range(0, len(a)):
                city = (a[x].split(' ')[-1])

            city = transliterate(city)
            city = city.title()

            res = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", 
                         params = {'q': city, 'units': 'metric', 'lang': 'ru', 'APPID': appid})
            data = res.json()
            town = data['name']
            temperture = data['main']['temp']
            feels_like = data['main']['feels_like']
            description = data['weather'][0]['description']

            temperture = float(temperture)
            feels_like = float(feels_like)
            temperture = math.ceil(temperture)
            feels_like = math.ceil(feels_like)
            
            if temperture != abs(temperture) and feels_like == abs(feels_like):
                temperture = math.fabs(temperture)
                temperture = round(temperture)
                feels_like = round(feels_like)
                speak(f'В городе {town} сейчас минус {temperture}, ощущается как {feels_like}, Погодные условия: {description}')
            elif feels_like != abs(feels_like) and temperture == abs(temperture):
                feels_like = math.fabs(feels_like)
                temperture = round(temperture)
                feels_like = round(feels_like)
                speak(f'В городе {town} сейчас {temperture}, ощущается как минус {feels_like}, Погодные условия: {description}')
            elif temperture == abs(temperture) and feels_like == abs(feels_like):
                temperture = round(temperture)
                feels_like = round(feels_like)
                speak(f'В городе {town} сейчас {temperture}, ощущается как {feels_like}, Погодные условия: {description}')
            elif temperture != abs(temperture) and feels_like != abs(feels_like):
                temperture = math.fabs(temperture)
                feels_like = math.fabs(feels_like)
                temperture = round(temperture)
                feels_like = round(feels_like)
                speak(f'В городе {town} сейчас минус {temperture}, ощущается как минус {feels_like}, Погодные условия: {description}')

    elif cmd == 'wikipedia':
    
        wikipediavoice = voice
        b = wikipediavoice.split('\n')
        for x in range(0, len(b)):
            wikiword = (b[x].split(' ')[-1])

        wikipedia.set_lang('Ru')
        ans = wikipedia.summary(wikiword)
        ans = re.sub(r'\(.+?\)\s', '', ans)
        answer = re.split("\. |\.\.\. ", ans)
        answer = answer[0]
        answer = rutranslate(answer)
        speak(answer)
        
    else:
    
        print('Команда не распознана, повторите!')


def transliterate(name):
   # Слоаврь с заменами
   slovar = {'а':'a','б':'b','в':'v','г':'g','д':'d','е':'e','ё':'e',
      'ж':'zh','з':'z','и':'i','й':'i','к':'k','л':'l','м':'m','н':'n',
      'о':'o','п':'p','р':'r','с':'s','т':'t','у':'u','ф':'f','х':'h',
      'ц':'c','ч':'cz','ш':'sh','щ':'scz','ъ':'','ы':'y','ь':'','э':'e',
      'ю':'u','я':'ja', 'А':'A','Б':'B','В':'V','Г':'G','Д':'D','Е':'E','Ё':'E',
      'Ж':'ZH','З':'Z','И':'I','Й':'I','К':'K','Л':'L','М':'M','Н':'N',
      'О':'O','П':'P','Р':'R','С':'S','Т':'T','У':'U','Ф':'F','Х':'H',
      'Ц':'C','Ч':'CZ','Ш':'SH','Щ':'SCH','Ъ':'','Ы':'y','Ь':'','Э':'E',
      'Ю':'U','Я':'YA',',':'','?':'',' ':'_','~':'','!':'','@':'','#':'',
      '$':'','%':'','^':'','&':'','*':'','(':'',')':'','-':'','=':'','+':'',
      ':':'',';':'','<':'','>':'','\'':'','"':'','\\':'','/':'','№':'',
      '[':'',']':'','{':'','}':'','ґ':'','ї':'', 'є':'','Ґ':'g','Ї':'i',
      'Є':'e', '—':''}
        
   # Циклически заменяем все буквы в строке
   for key in slovar:
      name = name.replace(key, slovar[key])
   return name


def rutranslate(word):
    # Á á Ó ó É é ý и́ ы́ э́ ю́ я́
    slovar = {'а́':'а', 'Á':'А', 'Ó':'О', 'о́':'о', 'É':'е', 'é':'е', 'ý':'у',
    'и́':'и', 'ы́':'ы', 'э́':'э', 'ю́':'ю', 'я́':'я'}

    for key in slovar:
        word = word.replace(key, slovar[key])
    return word


# запуск
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone() # запись голоса

speak_engine = pyttsx3.init() # голос с пк

with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source) # шумодав
        
stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback) # отправка записи m в функцию callback

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Так засуньте получение команд в цикл (while)  чтобы он перезапускался. А когда говорите стоп чтобы возвращал код для вызова break. B time.sleep(0.1) в конце непонятно для чего? получается ведь бесконечное зависание.

Comment: Возможно он использует  ```time.sleep(0.1)``` для меньшей загрузки системы

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то это:

```
speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()
while True:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    m = sr.Microphone()
    with m as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        
    stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Чисто технически должно сработать. Только вот не уверен, зачем вам эта `time.sleep(0.1)`, но решил оставить.

---

Всем добра-бобра

Comment: Проблема в том, что при таком цикле, когда голосовой помощник произносит ответ, то этот ответ так же записывается. После чего, он выводит это по нескольку раз и в итоге происходит краш.

Comment: Пока произносит усыпите слушателя